# How to Add an Image with Image Name in Ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I want to Display the Users Image with users name at the center of the user Image,
so how i can achieve this with responsive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNwkq.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any code to share that you've created in an attempt to solve this problem yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using existing CSS class **text-center** provided by Ionic.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/css-utilities/

Comment: I Have More Than one User Images and to display images one by one inline and users name respectively.

Comment: Do you want a list of images and a name (Given in a description, one below other)? You can use same structure within ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of positioning text over image:
HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" alt="Norway" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
  <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
  <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
  <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
  <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

AND CSS:

```
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

/* Bottom left text */
.bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

/* Top left text */
.top-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}

/* Top right text */
.top-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.bottom-right {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```